# UIActivityViewController - ordering of multiple images

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiimage, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to share an NSString containing text and 2 UIImages using UIACtivityViewController. I tried to have image `newPNG` followed by image `img` but always `img` appears before `newPNG` when I share.

```
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:  newPNG, img, text,  nil] applicationActivities:nil];
```

I tried different ordering in the array but the ordering of the images when I share via mail does not change.

Does it have to do with the sizes of the images or is there an alternative way to specify the order of images.

Comment: Did you get any solutions? I have the same issue. I  need to know how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: @zono I did not get any solution.